# Any established convention on symbols to use as multi-level separators?

Tags: coding-style

Let’s say that we want to encode recipes or dishes for `x` days in the form of a **string**. There can be an arbitrary number of days. Each day, we can have 0–3 of the following: breakfast, lunch, dinner. For each meal, there are multiple possible options ordered by preference (preferred option, fallback option etc.).

For example, let’s say that in our list there are 2 days: Day 1 and Day 2. On Day 1, we have breakfast, lunch and dinner, so 3 meals. On Day 2, there is only 1 meal, lunch. For Day 1, the options, in order of preference are `[eggs,muesli]` for breakfast, `[fish,lentils,pasta]` for lunch, and `[veggies]` for dinner. For Day 2 lunch, there is only 1 option: `[burger]`.

We need to use 3 different separators in order to encode this information as a string. For example, in top-down order, these can be `;`, `-` and `,`. In which case, the final string will be like this: `eggs,muesli-fish,lentils,pasta-veggies;-burger-`.

However, I am looking for an intuitive manner or established convention to pick the symbols. Any existing software documentation or known instance of a multi-level list using separators will work as an answer. I am looking for symbols that will be more easily identifiable as "top-level" and "bottom-level" respectively.

**PS**: I know that this information can be defined as a nested array but I would like for it to be a kind of configuration which can be input by a user with computer knowledge but who is not familiar with coding.

Comment: Find a better UX for inputting this than any kind of nested string.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Let's assume that the technology being used is limited to strings (a command line argument to a program, or something like that)

Comment: You're expecting non-coders to use command line arguments with very precise requirements around exactly how to separate strings? You're going to spend more time fixing bad data than you are anything else.

Comment: @PhilipKendall, that's a fair point, but let's assume that this is the only feasible option due to technical and/or time limitations.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @PhilipKendall It isn't. I'm actually in this situation due to technical limitations. It's a legacy program that can only take user input in the form of a string. Since it's an arbitrary number of days, we cannot separate the input into multiple strings. Of course, we could design a UI for inputting the information and which would internally convert the data into the string required as input to the program, but still the question remains on what is a human-friendly string representation for this kind of data.

Comment: There is no human friendly string representation of 3-dimensional data. It is difficult enough to show 3D data using an actual UI, let alone using only strings. Another fundamental problem is that of escaping, any common separator character may be present as data, so sooner or later someone will try to enter "fish-omelette" and everything will break.

Comment: @JonasH I am working with data where escaping is not an issue. I used recipes in my example but the actual data is different and will never include punctuation or separators.

Comment: Does this string allow multiple lines? Tabs? Is there a length limit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry but this

> eggs,muesli-fish,lentils,pasta-veggies;-burger-

is a train wreck of noise. It's far to difficult to see the structure here.

This is data. You need a data language. I'm a fan of JSON.

> There can be an arbitrary number of days. Each day, we can have 0–3 of the following: breakfast, lunch, dinner. For each meal, there are multiple possible options ordered by preference (preferred option, fallback option etc.).
>
> For example, let’s say that in our list there are 2 days: Day 1 and Day 2. On Day 1, we have breakfast, lunch and dinner, so 3 meals. On Day 2, there is only 1 meal, lunch. For Day 1, the options, in order of preference are [eggs,muesli] for breakfast, [fish,lentils,pasta] for lunch, and [veggies] for dinner. For Day 2 lunch, there is only 1 option: [burger].

```
{ 
  "days": [
    { 
      "day": "1",
      "breakfast": ["eggs", "muesli"],
      "lunch": ["fish", "lentils", "pasta"],
      "dinner": ["veggies"]
    },
    {
      "day": "2",
      "lunch": ["burger"]
    }   
  ]
}
```

You can pack all that into a single string. It is far easier on the eyes than your one liner. Normal humans can produce this if you provide them with an example to work from and quick feedback when they break it.

Or just give them a GUI to build this for them. Should save them from syntax errors and lets you keep them out of trouble.

P.S. If it's too much trouble to parse heterogeneous data then try this:

```
{ 
  "days": [
    { 
      "day": "1",
      "breakfast": ["eggs", "muesli"],
      "lunch": ["fish", "lentils", "pasta"],
      "dinner": ["veggies"]
    },
    {
      "day": "2",
      "breakfast": [""],
      "lunch": ["burger"],
      "dinner": [""]
    }   
  ]
}
```

Comment: This is actually a good option. The program only accepts a string as an input but we can use a JSON minifier to change the JSON to a single-line string first. Also, I found that there are tools like https://jsonforms.io/examples/basic where one can quickly generate a JSON from a user-friendly form.

Comment: @hb20007 one of the things I love about JSON is that it doesn't care about whitespace. So the whitespace is for the humans.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make this accessible to non-programmers, I think it's best to use something that they're familiar with: parentheses. You don't have to document anything new or surprising, just let parentheses do what they do:

```
((eggs muesli) (fish lentils pasta) (veggies))
(() (burger) ())
```

If you want to make it even more natural, you could add a few labels, which lets you get rid of the "dummy" empty values as well:

```
((day 1
      (breakfast eggs muesli)
      (lunch fish lentils pasta)
      (dinner veggies))
 (day 2
      (lunch fish lentils pasta)))
```

This also has the benefit of being very easy to parse.

Comment: HAHA, yeah, you can parse it as LISP. Just don't ask for a cheese burger. They'll think you'd rather have cheese than the burger.

Comment: @candied_orange That's okay, the actual data I'm dealing with will never have spaces. Also, it's possibly to replace the spaces with commas.

Comment: @hb20007 Hmm ok. If the spaces thing ever comes up and you've disallowed quotes you can always let them order a cheese_burger.